# phpunit mock multiple methods in a single call

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, refactoring

Have two mock methods `setAsy1` and `setAsy2` that returns the same values. Currently I need to call twice the same method function to setup mock methods. Is there any way I can setup with a single call?

```
$transferItemMockf->expects($this->any())
    ->method('setAsy1')
    ->willReturn($id);

$transferItemMockf->expects($this->any())
    ->method('setAsy2')
    ->willReturn($id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Builder\InvocationMocker::method()` can get `PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint` as parameter. So, you can set up mock from your example with a single call:

```
$transferItemMockf->expects($this->any())
   ->method($this->logicalOr(
        $this->equalTo('setAsy1'),
        $this->equalTo('setAsy2')
    ))
   ->willReturn($id);
```